# AjaxのJavaScriptが動きません

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajaxを使ったJavascriptで、以下の①と②は個別には問題なく動くのですが、
これを同時に使用とすると、②のwindow.onbeforeunload()関数が呼び出されません。
window.onbeforeunloadを使う場合の注意点などがありますか？

画面遷移時なので、console.log等も残せないようなので、デバッグにも苦労しています。
少し長くてすいませんが

コード①

```
<script language="JavaScript">
// ボタン無効の解除
// タイマーによる連続クリック防止を解除する
function buttonenable(){
    var btn_L = document.getElementById('button_L');
    var btn_R = document.getElementById('button_R');
    btn_L.disabled = false;
    btn_R.disabled = false;
}

//XMLHttpRequestオブジェクト生成
function createHttpRequest(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){  //Chrome,Firefoxなど
        return new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try {   //MSXML2以降用
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e) {
            try {   //旧MSXML用
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e2) {
                return null
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return null
    }
}
//POSTの準備、コールバック関数の指定、POST
function requestFile( data , method , fileName , async )
{
    //XMLHttpRequestオブジェクト生成
    var xhrobj = createHttpRequest();

    //open メソッド
    xhrobj.open( method , fileName , async );

    //サーバに対して解析方法を指定する
    xhrobj.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

    //send後のステータス変化毎のアクションを指定
    xhrobj.onreadystatechange = function()  {
        //readyState値は4で受信完了
        if (xhrobj.readyState==4)
        {
        //コールバック関数
        on_loaded(xhrobj);
        }
    }
    //send メソッド
    xhrobj.send( data);

    //連続クリック防止のため、ボタン無効タイマーを設定
    var btn_L = document.getElementById('button_L');
    var btn_R = document.getElementById('button_R');
    btn_L.disabled = true;
    btn_R.disabled = true;
    setTimeout('buttonenable()', 500);  //0.5秒ボタンを無効後に解除
}

//コールバック関数 ( 受信時に実行 )
function on_loaded(obj)
{
    //レスポンスを取得
    res  = obj.responseText;
    //デバッグ用、レスポンス内容をAlertDialogに表示
    alert(res);
}
</script>
```

コード②

```
<script language="JavaScript">
//画面遷移時の処理
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    var xhrobj = new XLMHttpRequest();
    //var hhrobj = createHttRequest();

    xhrobj.open("GET","/cgi-bin/stream_stop.py", true);
    xhrobj.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log(xhrobj.responseText);
    };
    xhrobj.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: 個別には動いているとのことなので念の為ですが、コード2 XLMHttpRequest と綴りが間違っているのは単にここに転記する際誤ったのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございました。タイプミスでした。コピペしたつもりだったので気づきませんでした。　一番恥ずかしいパターンでしたね